# Disable inner messagebox of a VSTO Outlook addin to visualize only my custom messagebox

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

i developed an addin for Outlook 2010 with VSTO mode.
the addin works good.
But i have a problem: i have customized the messagebox/popup with my own window.
When an exception was thrown now i have 2 messagebox, the mine and the one of the VSTO.
Is there a mode  to disable the messagebox of the VSTO mode, leaving only my custom messagebox??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also have my own customized messagebox used when there is any exception. But I dont rethrow the exception again so VSTO dont need to show another message.

**Suppress the exception after handling it and log it some where and use your own customized message box to display some meaningfull message to users**